# »Nach der Südstadt«

Tags: preposition

Heute habe ich am Görlitzer Bahnhof ein ganz alt aussehendes Schild mit der Aufschrift

> AUSGANG NACH DER SÜDSTADT

gesehen. Die Südstadt ist ein Görlitzer Stadtteil.

Bedeutet die Aufschrift *in die Südstadt* oder *in Richtung Südstadt* und folgt sie etwa alten Grammatikregeln, oder gibt es eine Erklärung, warum hier *nach der* und nicht *in die* verwendet wird?

Comment: Ich vermute, dass dies ein Dialektsymptom ist. Ähnlich wie in anderen Dialekten sowas gesagt wird wie "Ich geh mal nach'm ALDI", wenn gemeint wird, dass man zu ALDI geht. Hört sich für mich schlimm an, ich würde es, wenn ich Lehrer wäre und es ein Schülertext wäre, als Grammatikfehler anstreichen, denn für mich wäre "AUSGANG RICHTUNG SÜDSTADT" korrekt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"nach der" ist eine veraltete Richtungsangabe, wie du richtig erkannt hast.

Sie ist allerdings nicht deckungsgleich mit "in die Südstadt", weil das genau genommen implizieren würde, dass man, wenn man diesen Ausgang nimmt, direkt in der Südstadt steht.

Heute würde man wohl eher schreiben:

> Ausgang Richtung Südstadt

Wie oft, wenn man nach veralteten Wörtern/Bedeutungen sucht, hilft das Grimm'sche Wörterbuch:

> 1) die räumliche annäherung, bewegung, richtung nach oder zu einem ziele, mit einem verb oder substantiv der bewegung. der dativ drückt aus:
>   a) das ziel (person, ort, sache), nach dessen richtung hin oder bis zu welchem sich die bewegung erstreckt: mhd.

Wichtig für diese Bedeutung ist der Dativ im Artikel, der (der Artikel) heute mit *nach* mMn nicht mehr gebräuchlich ist, obwohl ihn der Duden in seinen Beispielen *das Zimmer liegt nach der Strasse* und *...nach dem Süden fahren*... noch erwähnt. In meinem persönlichen Sprachgebrauch kommt "nach" in räumlicher Verwendung nur noch vor Eigennamen und Himmelsrichtungen, und immer ohne Artikel, vor.

> wir fahren nach Amerika
>
> Fährt dieser Zug nach München?

Comment: Nach meiner Meinung (oder: nach dem Wörterbuch) fordert *nach*, egal ob kausal oder lokal verwendet, immer noch den Dativ, aber  ohne Artikel erkennt man es nicht so leicht.

Comment: Akzeptiert. Wahrscheinlich ist das ein nicht auf Anhieb erkennbarer Dativ.

Comment: @tofro In der Schulunterricht in Schweden wird immernoch die Reihe "aus, bei, mit, nach, seit, von, zu" gelernt als Präpositionen, die Dativ steuern. Ist dies also als veraltet zu betrachten?

Comment: @Beta, nein, meine Aussage ("gebräuchlich nur noch ohne Artikel, nur mit Eigennamen und Himmelsrichtungen") gilt 1. nur für *nach* in der räumlichen Verwendung "auf ein Ziel zu", und 2. ist das immer noch ein Dativ, auch wenn das Fehlen eines Artikels das schwierig macht, zu erkennen. Ich habe die Antwort leicht modifiziert, hoffentlich ist es jetzt klarer.

Comment: Ich kenne auch passiv "nach den Pilzen gehen" im Sinne von "auf Pilzsuche gehen" sowie "in die Pilze gehen".

Comment: Verwandt: "Der Junge kommt ganz nach der Mutter"?

Answer (score 2):

Heute wird *nach* hauptsächlich für Himmelsrichtungen (*nach Norden*), oder mit konkreten Namen, dann aber grundsätzlich ohne Artikel verwendet (*nach Stuttgart*) und im genannten Beispiel würde vermutlich *Zur Südstadt* (oder *In Richtung Südstadt*) stehen.

Wenn man mit Passieren des Ausgangs noch nicht in der Südstadt ist, ist *in die Südstadt* falsch, und ich denke, dass die Formulierung zum Ausdruck bringen möchte, dass man dort zur Südstadt kommen kann (aber vorher noch anderswo verbeikommt, oder bis in die Slowakei, wenn man weitergeht...).

Witzigerweise habe ich [hier](http://www.usatourist.com/deutsch/destinations/florida/miami/miami-airports.html) ein ganz aktuelles Beispiel gefunden,

> Eine Fahrt auf dem Super Shuttle nach der Innenstadt und dem Miami Hafen, dem Kreuzfahrthafen, kostet ungefähr $14.00. Ein Taxi nach der Innenstadt kostet ungefähr $22 und eine Einheitssumme von $24 zum Miami Hafen.

Comment: Ich befürchte, in deinem Link hat ein automatischer Übersetzer so einiges verbrochen: *...Die Miami-Dade Verkehrssystem Busse verbinden MIA und das Rapid Verkehrssystem, so dass es beiden Zugang erlaubt so weit südlich wie Marathon Key bis gerade nördlich der Miami-Dade/Broward County Grenze...*

Comment: @tofro: Das war auch mein erster Verdacht, aber es ist eine Übersetzerin namentlich genannt. Vielleicht hat sie alte Lehrbüchern des Großvaters herangezogen...

Comment: Cool, hab' ich garnicht gesehen. Merke: Nicht an jeder schlechten Übersetzung ist gleich Google schuld.

Comment: @guidot Ich denke das Beispiel aus dem Miamiflughafen nicht in der Antwort gehört, weil es keine interessante Information enthaltet. Fehlübersetzungen können alle Nichtmuttersprachler tun, was hier wahrscheinlich der Fall ist

Comment: @Beta zumindestens der von guidot genannte Satz mit "nach"  ist laut Duden *richtig*, allerdings m.A. nach veraltet/veraltend (auch wenn der Duden das nicht so sieht). Der von mir aus der gleichen Quelle zitierte Satz ist allerdings wirklich falsch und stellt daher die Quelle tatsächlich etwas in Zweifel.